# Opening a fireproof/waterproof HDD enclosure

Tags: backup

Quite a few years ago I procured the following fireproof/waterproof drive (**SentrySafe Fire-Safe Waterproof 250 GB Hard Drive #QA0005**):

[image]

It worked reasonably well (no complaints), although at 250GB the disk capacity was limited.  Now this drive has gone dead (PC does not recognize plugging/unplugging activity at all: tried it on multiple PCs) and I want to know how I can open the fireproof/waterproof enclosure, to see if I can still access the data.  I called SentrySafe but they have discontinued this product and they did not give me any meaningful instructions.

I don't see any screws or anything, so I don't know how to open it.  Does the enclosure need to be sawed off or something?

Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: Look for any 'rubber' bits you can prise out. Screws are likely underneath.

Comment: Also opening it up would reduce/remove the waterproofing

Comment: It all depends on how they sealed it and whether you want to maintain the integrity of the fireproof, waterproof enclosure. If they epoxied it together, the case will be destroyed in the process, but if they used silicone O-rings _(or other high temp material made into an O-ring)_ there's likely a way to separate the two pieces of the case _(have you looked on YouTube, googled how to take it apart?)_. Once the case is opened, there are also different ways they could have protected the electronics, one of which is pouring epoxy into the case, fully encasing all electronics, incl. the HDD.